# Airflow: how to force reparse of DAG definition file

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm using airflow 2.3.4 and primarily interact with airflow through the web UI.

Two questions:

- Is there a way to force a reparse of a DAG definition file in Airflow? How about all DAG definition files?
- Is there a way to check the last time a DAG file was parsed?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to force a reparse of a DAG definition file in Airflow? How about all DAG definition files?

First, you can use `dag-processor` command to manually parse all the files, the files in a subfolder or a specific dag file:

```bash
$ airflow dag-processor --help
usage: airflow dag-processor [-h] [-D] [-p] [-l LOG_FILE] [-n NUM_RUNS]
                             [--pid [PID]] [--stderr STDERR] [--stdout STDOUT]
                             [-S SUBDIR] [-v]

Start a standalone Dag Processor instance

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -D, --daemon          Daemonize instead of running in the foreground
  -p, --do-pickle       Attempt to pickle the DAG object to send over to the workers, instead of letting workers run their version of the code
  -l LOG_FILE, --log-file LOG_FILE
                        Location of the log file
  -n NUM_RUNS, --num-runs NUM_RUNS
                        Set the number of runs to execute before exiting
  --pid [PID]           PID file location
  --stderr STDERR       Redirect stderr to this file
  --stdout STDOUT       Redirect stdout to this file
  -S SUBDIR, --subdir SUBDIR
                        File location or directory from which to look for the dag. Defaults to '[AIRFLOW_HOME]/dags' where [AIRFLOW_HOME] is the value you set for 'AIRFLOW_HOME' config you set in 'airflow.cfg' 
  -v, --verbose         Make logging output more verbose
```

This command needs activating standalone dag processor by setting `AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__STANDALONE_DAG_PROCESSOR` to `True`.

By default, DagFileProcessor will skip parsing files when they are parsed since less than `AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__MIN_FILE_PROCESS_INTERVAL`, so you can set it to 0 to force the file processing.

To parse all the dags:

```bash
AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__STANDALONE_DAG_PROCESSOR=True AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__MIN_FILE_PROCESS_INTERVAL=0 airflow dag-processor -n 1
```

And to parse a specific dag file:

```bash
AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__STANDALONE_DAG_PROCESSOR=True AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__MIN_FILE_PROCESS_INTERVAL=0 airflow dag-processor -n 1 -S /path/to/dag/file
```

You can also do that with python, by loading the DagBag and call the `sync_to_db` method.

> Is there a way to check the last time a DAG file was parsed?

This time is available on wbeserver in `code` endpoint, and you can use `dags details` command to get the information:

```bash
airflow dags details <your dag id> -o json | jq '.[0].last_parsed_time'
```